# How to constrain index signature on Typescript to only allowable strings?

Tags: typescript

I have a use case where we have child classes that extend a parent class.  When an instance of the class is instantiated, I need the flexibility to allow any class variables as long as they are defined in the provided schema to the constructor. I have several constraints in an existing codebase I'm converting so I need to make this work.

A simplified version for example:

```
Class Foo {
  #fields: string[] // Populated dynamically in the constructor based on input schema
  [key: string]: any // Need to constrain this
}
```

My goal is simple, but I'm not sure how to pull it off (or if I can in TS).  I need to constrain the index signature so that [key: string]will allow any key of type string, as long as the key exists in the #fields array.

Comment: This isn't possible. If you intend on keeping the array constant throughout the lifetime of the class, consider creating a factory function that intersects the class type with a mapped type.

Comment: The fields array will be constant for the lifetime of the class, I'll go read up on factory functions and mapped types, thanks!